# How to get multiple Jquery scripts to work together

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to run two Jquery scripts, one called balancedgallery and the other museum. When I run each script by themselfs they run fine but together the balancedgallery script doesn't allow the Museum script to link the viewer and instead links directly to the image.

This could be because they are old scripts from 2014 and 2017 and some standards have changed? I had to update the ".load" to ".on('load')" for the balanced gallery reference. Though both the scripts are running fine (with no console errors). If I put "#msm-gallery-2" at the end of the url (2 being the image number) the viewer (Museum) displays.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <img src="https://www.ryanepp.com/assets/demos/balanced_gallery/moped1.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.ryanepp.com/assets/demos/balanced_gallery/moped2.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.ryanepp.com/assets/demos/balanced_gallery/moped3.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/enzzzooo/balanced-gallery/jquery.balanced-gallery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/enzzzooo/museum/jquery.museum.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.museum($('#content img'));
    });
</script>
  <script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
      $("#content").BalancedGallery({});
    } )
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs ... StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Can you create a [mcve]? All necessary code has to be in the question, not linked.

Comment: @jabaa I understand this and have been working on this for about a week and a half. I can't show the other pieces of code as they go above the 30k character limit (34k).

Comment: I'm not asking for the full code. I'm asking for a [mcve]. This is on step in [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Minimize and locate the problem. The goal of Stack Overflow is not to help one user with a problem. It's to help future users with similar problems. Links can break with time and problems become not reproducible and not helpful. Therefore it's required to post all necessary code in the question.

Comment: @Enzzzo 34k lines of code is not what *Minimal* means in [mcve]

Comment: @jabaa hey I get what you mean but I'm using a script that I didn't write. I updated the question to be more on what you guys are saying, clear, and self hosted it on github.

Comment: When you delete your GitHub repo, this question becomes worthless. That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is affecting your scripts at all, but you have an unclosed tag on line 1 - set this to `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US">`

and your last "img" tag is unclosed, which could be merging the div holding the scripts inside your last image.

Comment: Please don't post an answer for typos. That's a close reason.